# Projection, iterative calculations on time series, in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a block of concrete that changes in temperature over time. There is a heating element inside, and when turned on, it adds 1 degree per minute. When turned off the concrete block gives off heat to the environment and cools by 1 degree per minute.

The temperature must be kept within an interval given by a time series of pairs of min and max temperatures. 
    timeSeries = [ [0,2], [0,2], [0,2], [0,4], [0,4], [0,4], 
                 [0,4], [0,4], [3,4], [3,4], [3,4] ]

It works with a hysteresis, so it goes all the way up to max, then goes all the way down to min, then goes all the way up to max, etc.

I believe this is called projection, to calculate in iterations by looking at the results of the previous iteration. Or is it?

**Pseudo code:**

Every line can be computed with numbers form the previous. This is the formula:

```
incr = if       (T<=min): incrm = +1
       else if  (T>=min): incrm = -1
       else               incrm = incrm value from line above

T    = T from previous line plus incrm from previous line
```

**Example time series:**

```
T   incrm  min max
0     +1    0   2
1     +1    0   2
2     -1    0   2
1     -1    0   4
0     +1    0   4
1     +1    0   4
2     +1    0   4
3     +1    0   4
4     -1    3   4
3     +1    3   4
4     -1    3   4
```

**How is this well done in JS**

I know it's possible to hard code this with just creating a function that returns an associative array, when given the previous array. But I suspect there are elegant ways of doing this, by using some library.

The actual problem I am working on, is a lot more complex than the described one. But the essence is the same: to calculate new "rows" by looking at the previous, and by looking at values in a time series given beforehand.

Comment: A function with a loop (or recursion) does not sound hard coded. There might be libraries that do this already, but that's off-topic here.

Comment: Seems like what you are trying to accomplish, calculate the next values based off the previous values, is recursion.

Comment: Why is that off-topic? (Sincerely asking)

Comment: @MadsSkjern: Asking for libraries is off-topic. Such questions are not specific, and the answer is not clear.

Comment: I'm not asking for a library. I am asking how to do the job, and do it elegantly. The solution could be using a library.